# Probability - drawing balls from an urn

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An urn contains 17 balls marked LOSE and 3 balls marked WIN. You and an opponent take turns selecting a single ball at random from the urn without replacement. The person who selects the third WIN ball wins the game. It does not matter who selected the first two WIN balls. 
Q) If you draw first, find the probability that your opponent wins the game on his second draw?

What I tried: Possibilities: {W,W,L,W} {L,W,W,W} {W,L,W,W}
I summed up the probabilities and got an answer as 3/1140 = 1/380

The book's answer is 1/760

Where have I made the mistake?

Comment: It is $3 \cdot \frac {17}{20} \cdot \frac {3}{19} \cdot \frac {2}{18} \cdot \frac 1{17}$ which is $\frac 1{380}$.

Comment: I get $1/380$. My advice; take the "answers at the back of the book" with a grain of salt. These are generally produced as an afterthought, and with little, if any, quality control.

Comment: $\frac{1}{380}$ seems correct to me.

Comment: Unless you were in fact the author, your answer is correct.

Comment: You were right, and the book was wrong. Post your answer and accept it so that this isn't left as an unanswered question.